# Desglosar diccionario en dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, diccionarios

estoy realizando un recopilatorio de datos, donde he obtenido un diccionario. Este diccionario quiero convertirlo en un dataframe normal, para en un futuro poder exportarlo a csv.

Mi problema es el siguiente, donde con el siguiente código obtengo mi archivo json en un diccionario, y hago la conversión a dataframe:

```
with open("dicc.json", "r") as file:
    info = json.load(file)

df = pd.DataFrame() #Se crea un dataframe vacío para alojar los datos

for i in range(len(datos)):
    df = df.append(pd.json_normalize(info[str([i+1])])) #Añadimos a cada una de las filas cada uno de los registros extraídos
```

El problema viene cuando me doy cuenta que dentro de mi diccionario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si por ejemplo entro a la clave 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede apreciar que hay listas y más diccionarios. Al pasar estos datos a dataframe no pasarían como str y quedarían así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde por ejemplo la columna challenges en vez de una lista, a mi me gustaría que challenges_id fuese otra columna nueva del dataframe, e ir desglosando todas esas listas de los diccionarios en nuevas columnas.

¿Sabéis cómo se podría ir navegando por el diccionario para así a la hora de convertir el diccionario en dataframe no me cree registros que sean literalmente listas, si no que cada registro de esa lista sea una columna nueva del dataframe?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

No hay una forma sencilla o directa desde `pandas` de hacer lo que solicitas. Lo que puedes hacer es crear una función, seleccionar las columnas que deseas expandir (En realidad sería aplanar, del inglés `flatten`, las columnas).

La función para aplanar las columnas podría recibir dos argumentos, el `dataframe` original y las columnas que deseas aplanar y utilizar `pandas.json_normalize` para aplanar dichas columnas.

Luego de ser aplanadas y guardadas en un `dataframe` temporal, puedes utilizar [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) para concatenar las nuevas columnas aplanadas al `dataframe` original.

Si no necesitas la columna original la puedes eliminar con [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Ya que no pusiste tus datos, cree un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar a tus necesidades. En el futuro asegurate de siempre agregar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en todas tus preguntas.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

# Función para aplanar las columnas seleccionadas
def flatten_columns(df, columns_to_flatten):
    df_result = df.copy()

    for col in columns_to_flatten:
        # Normalizar la columna indicada
        df_expanded = pd.json_normalize(df_result[col])

        # Renombrar las columnas creadas tras la normalización añadiendo el nombre de la columna original como prefijo
        df_expanded.columns = [f'{col}_{subcol}' for subcol in df_expanded.columns]

        # Concatenar las columnas obtenidas en el dataframe original
        df_result = pd.concat([df_result, df_expanded], axis=1)

        # Eliminar la columna original
        df_result = df_result.drop(col, axis=1)

    return df_result

# Ejemplo de uso
d = {'Col1': [1, 2, 3], 'Col2': [{'A': 10, 'B': 20}, {'A': 30, 'B': 40}, {'A': 50, 'B': 60}],
     'Col3': [{'X': 100, 'Y': 200}, {'X': 300, 'Y': 400}, {'X': 500, 'Y': 600}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Dataframe original
print(df)

# Especificar las columnas a expandir/aplanar
columns_to_flatten = ['Col2', 'Col3']

df_result = flatten_columns(df, columns_to_flatten)

# Dataframe resultante
print(df_result)
```

Esto imprime el dataframe original (Con las columnas que contienen diccionarios) y el dataframe resultante (Con las columnas aplanadas):

```
   Col1                Col2                  Col3
0     1  {'A': 10, 'B': 20}  {'X': 100, 'Y': 200}
1     2  {'A': 30, 'B': 40}  {'X': 300, 'Y': 400}
2     3  {'A': 50, 'B': 60}  {'X': 500, 'Y': 600}
   Col1  Col2_A  Col2_B  Col3_X  Col3_Y
0     1      10      20     100     200
1     2      30      40     300     400
2     3      50      60     500     600
```